# the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for

Tags: python, django, powershell

I'm not sure what is causing this error I'm looking to try and runsever on django from windows PowerShell but im am getting that error and this wall of issues.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03D366A8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "D:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Python\courseworkupload\courseworkupload\urls.py", line 26, in <module>
    url(r'^upload/', include('.upload.urls')),
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "D:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 121, in import_module
    raise TypeError(msg.format(name))
TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '.upload.urls'
```

This was done after i ran python manage.py runserver

Any help on the issue would be great

Edit: Adding tree below

```
C:.
│   db.sqlite3
│   manage.py
│
├───.idea
│       courseworkupload.iml
│       misc.xml
│       modules.xml
│       workspace.xml
│
├───courseworkupload
│   │   settings.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   wsgi.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           settings.cpython-35.pyc
│           urls.cpython-35.pyc
│           wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│
└───upload
    │   admin.py
    │   apps.py
    │   forms.py
    │   models.py
    │   tests.py
    │   urls.py
    │   views.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───migrations
    │       __init__.py
    │
    ├───templates
    └───__pycache__
            admin.cpython-35.pyc
            forms.cpython-35.pyc
            models.cpython-35.pyc
            urls.cpython-35.pyc
            views.cpython-35.pyc
            __init__.cpython-35.pyc
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The leading dot in `include('.upload.urls')` is causing the problem.

Assuming that `upload` is in your project directory (the one that contains `manage.py`), changing it to `upload.urls` should work.

```
url(r'^upload/', include('upload.urls')),
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help you where right and its stopped me pulling my hair out! thank you!

Comment: Is this only a problem in the newer version of python? I don't recall having this problem before.

Comment: @daraul I’m not sure to be honest. The original question is using Python 3.5 (released 2015), so it’s not a recent change to Python that caused the error. I haven’t tested Python 2.7, but it has the same signature for `import_module` so I suspect you’d get the same error.